# MSMQ Authenticated Queues

Tags: .net, authentication, msmq

I am struggling to find information on the risks of not setting the "Authenticated" check box on an MSMQ message queue and under which conditions it is a must. I need to prevent unauthorized parties from being able to read/write from/to a queue. When not setting the value, I am greeted with the ominous warning:

> Queue is unauthenticated. Message senders can bypass the Access Control settings specified in the Security tab.

I have tested attempting a connection to the queue (Authenticated unchecked) running my service process under a domain user profile which have not been given access to the message queue using the Access Control settings. I am blocked access to the queue with a nice error message:

> Access to Message Queuing system is denied.

Which is what I was expecting.

Some questions I have:

- What is the point of being able to set Access Control on the queue if it can be bypassed (somehow)?
- Under what circumstances can the Access Control settings be bypassed?
- What are the benefits of enabling the Authenticated above just configuring access using the ACL settings?

I am trying to find out whether I can get away with not having to go the Authenticated Queue route without compromising security (or at least knowing what compromises I will be making).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"What is the point of being able to set Access Control on the queue if it can be bypassed (somehow)?" 
You could apply that reasoning to ANY security technique. ACLs restrict casual/accidental access. They're fine where the message data is of no use to anyone else but you.

"Under what circumstances can the Access Control settings be bypassed?"
You can sniff the network packets for the SID of a user in the ACL. Then you can craft an MSMQ frame (rather than going through the MSMQ queue manager) and get access.

"What are the benefits of enabling the Authenticated above just configuring access using the ACL settings?"
Better security. Does require the infrastructure to support authentication, such as Active Directory or the use of external certificates. It's a cost/benefit analysis in the end.

Bottom line - Queue ACLs are insecure.